# Eigen compilation error with gcc 8.2.1 on MSYS2

Tags: c++, gcc, eigen, eigen3, msys2

We are [facing errors](https://github.com/MRtrix3/mrtrix3/issues/1521) compiling against Eigen 3.3.7 (and probably older versions) against the latest versions of GCC 8.2.1 supplied by MSYS2. Strangely, this only happens with the latest builds of the same package (`mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc` 8.2.1):

- 8.2.1+20181123-1 : fine
- 8.2.1+20181130-1 : error
- 8.2.1+20181207-1 : error

The error is:

```
In file included from C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/SparseCore:50,
                 from C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/Sparse:26,
                 from C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen:2,
                 from src/registration/transform/search.h:21,
                 from src/registration/transform/initialiser_helpers.cpp:20:
C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseBlock.h: In member function 'Eigen::internal::sparse_matrix_block_impl<SparseMatrixType, BlockRows, BlockCols>::BlockType& Eigen::internal::sparse_matrix_block_impl<SparseMatrixType, BlockRows, BlockCols>::operator=(const BlockType&)':
C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseBlock.h:216:33: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
       return operator=<BlockType>(other);

                             ^
```

I'm assuming this is a bug in the GCC package supplied by MSYS2, rather than Eigen (the `SparseBlock.h` file hasn't changed for a while, as far as I can tell). Are the different GCC builds based on the same source code? Any idea what the issue might be?

---

EDIT: here is a MCVE:

**test.cpp:**

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
int main () { return 0; }
```

**compile with g++ 8.2.1 (version 8.2.1+20181130-1 or newer - no error with older version):**

```
$ g++ $(pkg-config --cflags eigen3) test.cpp -o test
In file included from C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/SparseCore:50,
                 from C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/Sparse:26,
                 from C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/Eigen:2,
                 from test.cpp:1:
C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseBlock.h: In member function 'Eigen::internal::sparse_matrix_block_impl<SparseMatrixType, BlockRows, BlockCols>::BlockType& Eigen::internal::sparse_matrix_block_impl<SparseMatrixType, BlockRows, BlockCols>::operator=(const BlockType&)':
C:/Users/donald/msys64/mingw64/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseBlock.h:216:33: error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
       return operator=<BlockType>(other);
                                 ^
```

Comment: The question should include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: Apologies - I've now edited the main post to add the MCVE.

Comment: I can't easily install g++8.2.1 here, so I can't verify nor find a workaround. You could try adding a space between the `=` and `<` in the offending line. And of course you should send a bug-report to the gcc developers (if possible try to reduce it to an example which just contains a templated `operator=`).

Comment: The issue is not gcc 8.2.1 per se - the MCVE compiles fine with an earlier MSYS2 build of that version of gcc, and also compiles fine on gcc 8.2.1 on my Arch Linux system. This is likely most likely specific to MSYS2's packaging. I'm hoping the MSYS2 developers  (e.g. @RayDonnelly?) are monitoring this forum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further investigation suggests this is indeed a GCC bug. I've [reported this on GCC Bugzilla](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88564), and I'll close this thread. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, system wouldn't let me - had to wait 9 hours before I could accept my own answer apparently...

Comment: Some more info about the Debians tracker for this bug https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=915934.