# How to patch Eigen 3.3.7 to workaround a GCC 8.2.1 bug (arm-none-eabi 8-2018q4-major toolchain)?

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, eigen

I was trying to compile Eigen 3.3.7 with [Arm's bare metal 8-2018q4-major toolchain](https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+announcement/15181) and see the very same error (see the [x86_64 variant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53842888/eigen-compilation-error-with-gcc-8-2-1-on-msys2)).

It was just plain unlucky for ARM to pick an affected snapshot (20181213) as their release. Embedded toolchain is nightmare-ish to patch so I opt to patch Eigen instead.

Is this the right way of doing so? ([source](https://github.com/libigl/eigen/blob/1f05f51517ec4fd91eed711e0f89e97a7c028c0e/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseBlock.h#L214-L217)) to workaround this GCC bug?

```
    inline BlockType& operator=(const BlockType& other)
    {
-      return operator=<BlockType>(other);
+      return this->operator=(other);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think that patch is correct, it will end up calling itself instead of the other `operator=`

Comment: see if  `return operator=( static_cast<const SparseMatrixBase<BlockType>&>(other) );`  compiles  (I don't have that compiler version installed to test)

Comment: Don't have GCC either, but what about `auto assign = &sparse_matrix_block_impl::operator<BlockType>` ? A comment in the other question suggested that even a space between `= <` might help.

Comment: If the suggestion of @M.M does not work, you could try putting the functionality into a method (name it `assign(const SparseMatrixBase<OtherDerived>& other)`, for example) and have both `operator=` call that function.